# What to do if I can't connect to the router

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I accidentally logged out of the WIFI on my phone, and forgot the password. I'm connected to the internet on my PC with an Ethernet cable, and want to open the router IP, but I can't. I've looked at the back of the router, I've looked at it through cmd, both say that the address is 192.168.1.1, but when I try to type it in the browser, it gives out an error. I've tried pinging it, everything normal. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: What error shows when you navigate to `192.168.1.1`? If it's a trust error regarding the SSL cert, there will be a button or link below the error you can click to open the trust options so you can force load the page. If the error is the IP isn't available to navigate to, reboot the router, wait ~60s then try again, but if that still doesn't result in anything, reset the router to default and re-set it up/load a backup config file of the settings

Comment: Can you still connect to `192.168.1.1` from the PC's browser? There is a chance that it will remember the login (if you have set this option).

Comment: On Firefox it just tells that there was an error, on Chrome it tells that the website doesn't allow connection, with the error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". In another post I've seen that I should turn off my router, then turn it on after 15 seconds and try to log into the router before the firewall activates. So I did, and managed to log in, but couldn't change anything. I've tried disabling and activating again, but I always failed to be quick enough to change any settings.

Comment: Now, which genius has just downvoted all the answers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with build 23466 of Windows 11, you can see your
saved SSID keys in plain text by:

- Run *Settings > Network and internet > Wi-Fi*
- Click *Manage known networks*
- Click your saved SSID
- Next to "View Wi-Fi security key", click the *View* button
  and your password will be displayed.

Source :
[You can finally view all your saved Wi-Fi passwords in the latest Windows 11 preview](https://www.theverge.com/2023/5/24/23736197/microsoft-windows-11-wifi-passwords-insider-preview).

Comment: Sorry for such a long absence, I forgot to tell you that I use Windows 7. Thing is, my PC components are too bad to handle Windows 10 or 11, at least that's what I've been told.

Comment: What model is the router?

Comment: FiberHome HG6245D

Comment: The manual is [here](https://wirelessshop.mx/download/Product_Manual_HG6244C.pdf). It says that the factory defaults for the Administrator login are Username:admin and Password:admin. Try these first. If this doesn't work, you could factory-reset the router, but you will lose all the setting on the router which might be a problem.

Comment: On the physical router, it says that the username and password are: Login:user, Password:user1234, and I've been able to successfully enter the router menu when I tried disabling and enabling the router, essentially bugging the firewall. The problem is, I just can't get access to the router site itself. When I try to load the page, it gives out an error, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Still, thanks. I will read the manual now.

Comment: Just a note : On some routers the user menu is a truncated version of the admin menu. I don't know if yours is also like this.

Comment: Through turning the router on and off every second, I managed to see the password. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would reset it (there's probably a little hole for the reset, or just a regular "reset" button) and then check the manual of the router.